# "cut the corner" and "cut corners"

Tags: differences

I am not a native English speaker. 
I would like to know the difference of followings, if any

1. cut the corner
2. cut corners

I searched the meaning of the two (in English-Japanese online dictionary).

1. cut the corner: to take shortcuts
2. cut corners: to take an easy way / goof off

They are not interchangeable. Is it correct?
Or, do you use them interchangeably?

In Merriam-Webster, I found

- [cut corners](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cut%20%20corners): to perform some action in the quickest, easiest, or cheapest way

Comment: To *cut **a** corner* means to take a diagonal path across a lawn, or some similar short-cut. The term can be applied to driving as well as walking. You could use *cut **the** corner* when referring to a specific junction. To *cut corners* means as you dictionary definition says.

Comment: beware of dictionaries.  I am a native speaker of American English  (and o know a good bit of Japanese) and I do not believe I have ever heard anybody say "cut the corner".

Comment: In BrE at least "cutting the corner" is a (usually dangerous) manoeuvre when driving where the vehicle is driven on the wrong side of the road around the apex of a bend. It can also describe, as @Mick says, walking or driving at a diagonal over part of an open space when the path or roadway goes around it. Long vehicles sometimes have to cut corners in this sense to turn into side streets which can be dangerous for cyclists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we never say "cut *the* corners".

it's very subtle.  I just asked some friends. one says "don't cut that corner" is ok - but only if "that corner" is well-defined.  however the concensus is that "cut corners" is standard.

Comment: Then prove it. :)

Comment: @choster: gladly.  just tell me what counts as proof.

Comment: Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of our standards and practices. A good answer should explain *why* — it should be useful to any future visitors who have the same problem, and as such should include appropriate references or examples. What you have provided is a personal assertion, but you haven't provided any reason why your assertion is superior to any other anonymous assertion on the Internet. StackExchange strives to be better than Yahoo Answers or the average discussion forum.

Comment: is it formal written expression?

Comment: I'd say it's informal, but it could be used in e.g. a report, as in "The project failed because the team cut too many corners" or something like that.